# Inputting numbers in char array

Tags: c++

In reference to this [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/JULKA/) I need to input a 100 digit number in the program and perform operations on it. I figured I would use a char array to do it.

I wrote this code after trying for some time.

```
 int main()
 {
 //int cases=10;

//while(cases--)
//{
    int i;
    char totalapples[102];
    //char klaudia_apples[200] , natalia_apples[200];

    for(i=0;totalapples[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
            cin>>totalapples[i];
    }

    //cin>>moreapples[200];
    //cout<<moreapples[200];

    while(i--)
    {
      cout<<totalapples[i];
    }
//}

    return 0;
  }
```

When I run this, I get the following result:

```
Input : 1234657891234567981345698
Output : 987564321
```

Can anybody tell what is happening??

Comment: Your first loop will create undefined behavior. Initialize the array to zero.

Comment: This condition tests for uninitialized memory: `totalapples[i]!='\0'`. Also `cin>>totalapples[i];` just reads a single character.

Comment: _"I figured I would use a char array to do it."_ Why?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - "`cin>>totalapples[i];` just reads a single character." That's the idea. It's a 100 char string, being used as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes undefined behavior. Despite the fact the `char` array contains undefined values you attempt to read from it using

```
totalapples[i]!='\0'
```

in your `for` loop. Instead, read the whole string into a `std::string`:

```
string totalApplesStr;
cin >> totalApplesStr;
```

Now you can iterate over `totalApplesStr`:

```
for (char c : totalApplesStr) {
     /* Do whatever you need to */
}
```

Or, if that isn't a logical error in your code, you can iterate from the end to the beginning:

```
for (auto it = totalApplesStr.rbegin(); it != totalApplesStr.rend(); ++it) {
    /* Do whatever you need to */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a char array.

You may then use [std::tranform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to convert to a vector of int to do your big number computations.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to test values from an array that has not been initialized yet.

Although a char array is the *least* safe method you could use for this, you could fix it with an initializer:

```
char totalapples[102] = {0};
```

Also, your second loop will print the result backwards. Try incrementing *to* `i`, not decrementing *from* `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You new initialize your counter/index. And there are many other improvement to be done, but your code was short

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 102

int main {
    char totalapples[ARRAY_SIZE];
    unsigned int i = ARRAY_SIZE;
    i = 0;
    while (i < ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        cin>>totalapples[i]; // range is 0..101
        i++;
    }    

    i = ARRAY_SIZE;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        cout<<totalapples[i]; // range is 0..101
        i--; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: This will input the number backwards.

Comment: The first loop invokes undefined behavior, ironically.

Comment: Sorry, wrote it on te go, It is not copy paste code, it is example code.

Comment: If was because it access the element [0-1]